# AWS Cognito Multi-Factor Authentication using the Hosted UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication

I'm trying to set up the MFA for my application using Amazon Cognito and its hosted UI.
I set up the MFA on the Amazon Cognito Console as required and using the TOTP.

When I try logging in, I get this error on the hosted UI, the 2nd window for MFA doesn't show and I get [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VcuO.png):
You must have multi-factor authentication (MFA) set up to sign in. Please set up MFA and try again.

Is there something I forgot to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is anything you have forgotten. [Hosted UI setup with the Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-integration.html) doesn't support users setting up their software MFA token.